# Не может найти Message.Builder

Tags: android-sdk

AndroidStudio не видит Message.Builder. Пишет Cannot resolve symbol 'Builder'
Импортировал android.os.Message; Нашел похожий [вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54827397/in-message-builder-builder-is-showing-unresolved-reference), но не нашел ответ.

Еще поискав в интернете я понял что импорт должен быть следующим:
import com.google.firebase.messaging.Message;
Но когда я добавляю зависимость implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:18.0.0' класс Message внутри его нету.
Приходится добавлять implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:6.8.1' и вроде бы все нормально, класс Message есть и он работает. Но опять, класс FirebaseMessaging перестал работать. Это из за того, что в admin тоже есть такой класс. У меня не получается дальше продвинуться, не знаете что мне нужно делать ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я хотел отправлять уведомления через FCM (Firebase Cloud Messaging).

Я не понял почему происходит это ошибка, и написал свой класс SendNotification. 
Ссылка на проект с классом. Там вы так же можете посмотреть как принимать уведомление.
https://github.com/MuhaPW/FirebaseSendNotification

**Не забудьте изменить API_KEY в методе sendNotification();**

**FCM API KEY, а не проекта!**